# sublime text 2 ui libraries

Tags: sublimetext

What libraries does sublime text 2 uses for the UI interface? The tabs looks great and the ui seems pretty neat. Is this a python UI library or does the creator made his widgets.

Comment: Why don't you ask him? His contact information is all over the [site](http://sublimetext.com/2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 is mostly coded in C++ and uses a custom UI toolkit (per http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2822114).